# What is an involutive operator

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

Please help me in understanding this:

I have to find the eigen values of an involutive operator. So what exactly is an involutive operator? I mean I need one example for an involutive operator.

Note:
I know that an operator A with property $ A^2 $ = **1** is involutive operator so does that mean $\begin{bmatrix}
0  &1 \\ 
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $
 and $\begin{bmatrix}
1  &0 \\ 
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix} $ are involutive operators???

Comment: Yes, the two matrices you wrote are two examples of involutive operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is a linear involutive operator $A: V \longrightarrow V$, $v \in V$ an eigenvector of $A$ ($v \neq 0$), $\lambda$ an eigenvalue such that $Av = \lambda v$.

Then $v = A^2v = A(\lambda v) = \lambda(Av) = \lambda^2 v$

hence $\lambda^2 = 1$. This implies that $\lambda = \pm1$.

Comment: Perfect!!! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

An involution is an operator that is its own inverse, i.e. $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{A}^{-1}$, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)#Linear_algebra). This implies that $\mathbf{A}^2=\mathbf{I}$, therefore your two matrices are in fact examples of involutions.